# Убрать второй или третий знак '!' в строке с помощью регулярного выражения. PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, выборка

Всем привет!

Есть строка`$string = aaa!bbbb!ccccc!ddddd!eeeeee!ffffff!gggg!...и до бесконечности`

Мне нужно составить регулярное выражение, меняющее произвольный восклицательный знак на `X`.

Повторений восклицательных знаков через n-e количество символов может быть хоть миллион, поэтому такие варианты:

```
preg_replace('/^[^!]+/i', 'X', $string); //меняем первый по счету
preg_replace('/^([^!]+)(!)([^!])/i', 'X', $string); //меняем второй по счету
preg_replace('/^([^!]+)(!)([^!])(!)([^!])/i', 'X', $string); //меняем третий по счету...
```

...не подходят

Подскажите, как сделать такой паттерн(регулярное выражение на выборку), чтобы сменой одной цифры выбирать какой `!` менять. Грубо говоря: поставил где-то 1, поменялся первый, поставил 2, поменялся второй и т.д.

Спасибо!

Comment: Нужна поддержка preg_replace, или str_replace тоже подойдет?

Comment: давай str_replace тоже))) Но интересовала именно возможность поиска и замены по регулярному выражению

Comment: посмотрите ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$text = "aaa!bbbb!ccccc!ddddd!eeeeee!ffffff!gggg!";

$number = 2;
$replace = preg_replace ('/!/e',"\$number--==1?'X':'\\0'", $text);

echo $replace;
```

И с callback для желающих -.-

```
$text = "aaa!bbbb!ccccc!ddddd!eeeeee!ffffff!gggg!";
$number = 3;
$replace = preg_replace_callback('/!/',
           function ($match) use (&$number) {return $number--==1?'X':$match[0];},
           $text);
echo $replace;
```

Результат:

```
aaa!bbbb!cccccXddddd!eeeeee!ffffff!gggg!
```

Comment: мне кажется заминусовали за то, что сейчас модификатор `e` не используется, и функция заменяется на `preg_replace_callback`

Comment: @Let'ssayPie -.- чем тебе не угодил `e` не знаю, но его может и редко используют, но сейчас он идеально сюда подходит. `preg_replace_callback` - намного медленнее будет.

Comment: мне никогда не нравилось, но я плюс поставил :D upd: всегда при `e` мне вылетали предупреждения, люблю чистенько, хд)

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то вы хотите по паттерну заменить n-ый найденный элемент в строке, тогда вот вам пример:

```
$string = 'aaa!bbbb!ccccc!ddddd!eeeeee!ffffff!gggg!';

echo preg_replace_n('/!/', 'X', $string, 2); // 2 - второе вхождение

function preg_replace_n($search, $replace, $string, $counter)
{
    $string = preg_replace_callback($search, function ($m) use (&$counter, $replace) {
        if ($counter-- == 1) return $replace;
        return $m[0];
    }, $string);

    return $string;
}
```

На выходе получаем:

```
aaa!bbbbXccccc!ddddd!eeeeee!ffffff!gggg!
```

Comment: Ухххх.... Осталось еще и входную строку подтюнить чтоб '/' не было, пару проверочек на входной /, и можно на гитхуб

Comment: @Manitikyl, вы о preg_quote?

Comment: действительно, да именно о нем

Comment: @Manitikyl, я пока не достоин гитхуба) только если пронхуб))))) если хотите, можете исправить мой ответ с проверкой, приму)

Comment: Та лан, так тож нормуль, там уже некс вопрос. Просто изменить первыйпараметр на `'/'.preg_quote($search).'/'` как нить так.

Comment: @Manitikyl, если уж говорить о классе и гитхубе, то класс с 1 функцией это не класс), хотя можно подумать об этом, интересная штука. а еще я думаю, что тернарная логика в вашем решении смотрится красивее. на счет preg_qoute, щас справлю)

Comment: не класс а либа :D щас еще пару ответиков по регулярком и этот банк можно оформлять. P.S. автор уже забил на этот топик, там некст есть.

Comment: @Manitikyl, никакого уважения к ответам :(

Answer (score 0):

Это решается с помощью preg_replace_callback()

*(preg_replace() с модификатором `e` в последних версиях php удалена!)*:

```
$str = 'aaa!bbbb!ccccc!ddddd!eeeeee!ffffff!gggg!';
$need = 1;

echo preg_replace_callback(
    '~\!~',
    function($m)use($need){
        static $i = 0;
        return ++$i == $need ? 'X' : $m[0];
    },
    $str
);
```

Результат:

```
aaaXbbbb!ccccc!ddddd!eeeeee!ffffff!gggg!
```